# Random date in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, random, intervals

I'm trying to generate a random date on postgres as the enddate and a second date a week before as the startdate. I tried with the following request but it doesn't work. : /
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
SELECT date((current_date - trunc(random() * 365) * '1 day'::interval)) as enddate,
date(enddate - '7 day'::interval) as startdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse a computed column in the same scope as it was defined. Repeating the expression is not an option here, since the computation is not deterministic. An approach uses a subquery:

```
SELECT enddate,  enddate - '7 day'::interval startdate
FROM (
    SELECT date(current_date - trunc(random() * 365) * '1 day'::interval) as enddate
) t
```

Comment: Additionally: `date((current_date - trunc(random() * 365) * '1 day'::interval))` can be simplified to `current_date - (random() * 365)::int`

Answer (score 0):

Function to generate random date from now to NNN days back:

```
create or replace function app.get_random_date(
  p_days_look_back int
)
  returns timestamp as
$$
declare
  v_interval interval;
  v_result timestamp;
begin
  v_interval := make_interval(days => p_days_look_back);
  v_result := now() - v_interval +  random() * v_interval;
  return v_result;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```